# Binding method to dynamically created labels

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a Tkinter frame that is essentially showing a group of thumbnails, displayed in Label widgets.  I need the Labels to be created dynamically to accommodate differing numbers of thumbnails to generate. I have a generated list of file names, and can create the thumbnails as needed, but when I try to bind a function to each of the created labels, it seems to be over ridden by the last created Label/Binding. The result is that only the final label has the method bound to it.

```
import tkinter as tk

class test(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args)
        self.shell = tk.Frame(self)
        self.shell.pack()
        self.create_widgets()


    def create_widgets(self):
        '''
        Two rows of labels
        '''
        for row in range(2):
            for i in range(5):
                text = 'Thumbnail\nrow{}\ncolumn{}'.format(row,i)
                self.thumb = tk.Label(self.shell,                                     
                                     text = text)
                self.thumb.grid(row = row, column = i, sticky = 'news')
                self.thumb.bind("<Button-1>",lambda x: self.click(self.thumb))

    def click(self, *args):
        #This should affect only the Label that was clicked
        print('CLICK!')



app = test()
root = app
root.mainloop()
```

The method being called will always be the same, but how do I identify the Label to be effected?

Comment: your example doesn't work - you bind function `self.test()` but you have only `self.click()`. And what is `self.card` ?

Comment: sorry, bad editing from original code on my part, fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least three solutions.

The first is the simplest: the function is passed an event object that contains a reference to the widget:

```
label = tk.Label(...)
label.bind("<Button-1>", self.click)
...
def click(self, event):
    print("you clicked:", event.widget)
```

If you prefer to use lambda, you can pass the label itself to the function:

```
label = tk.Label(...)
label.grid(...)
label.bind("<Button-1>",lambda event, label=label: self.click(label))
```

Another solution is to keep a reference to every label in a list, and pass the index to the function:

```
self.labels = []
for row in range(2):
    for i in range(5):
        label = tk.Label(...)
        label.grid(...)
        self.labels.append(label)
        index = len(self.labels)
        label.bind("<Button-1>",lambda event, i=index: self.click(i))
...
def click(self, index):
    print("the label is ", self.labels[index])
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much! Lambda is still pretty slippery for me!

Comment: @Kelly: I've updated my answer to show how to do it without lambda. IMO, you should only use lambda if you _need_ to use lambda, and it looks like you may not need to use lambda.

Comment: Much appreciated, I was working with lambda because it seemed like I was in need of passing the widget as an argument in the event binding,  always good to see alternate working methods!

Answer (score 0):

When you click label then tk runs function with `event object` which you skip using `lambda x`.

You need

```
lambda event:self.click(event, ...)
```

and then in `click` you can use `event.widget` to get clicked widget.

```
def click(event, ...);

   print('Widget text:', event.widget['text'])
```

---

You had problem with `self.thumb` in `self.click(self.thumb)` because you don't know how works `lambda` in `for` loop. (and it is very popular problem :) )

`lambda` is `"lazy"`. It doesn't get value from `self.thumb` when you declare `lambda x: self.click(self.thumb)` but when you click button (and you execute `lambda`. But when you click label then `for` loop is finished and `self.thumb` keeps last value.

You have to use this method to get correct value when you declare `lambda`

```
labda event, t=self.thumb: self,clikc(t)
```